# Multiply a integer by itself

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

The program can't exceed 100. I have tried different ways, and either it doesn't produce any output, or it's infinite. Output should be `8 16 32 64`.

This code is the closest I have been, but it doesn't produce output. Any help would be appreciated.

```
num_insects = 8 # Must be >= 1

while num_insects > 8:
    num_insects *= 2  
    print(num_insects)
```

Comment: There is already an answer here that should point you in the right direction, but let me give you some advice to further your programming career. You should learn about debugging, this would help you tremendously in figuring out why the program is behaving in a certain way.

Comment: Thank you both. @Lasse I have been debugging and solved some on my own, but sometimes my eyes gloss over when I only sleep a couple of hours a night in order to finish school and work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not checking if `num_insects` is exceeding 100. Also, you should print before you double the number.

```
num_insects = 8 # Must be >= 1

while num_insects <= 100:
    print(num_insects)
    num_insects *= 2
```

Comment: Thank you @Ahmad.I appreciate it!